# C++/CX property throwing error on set

Tags: c++, properties, windows-phone-8, c++-cx

I have a class:

```
ref class Coord
{
public:
    property float X {
        float get() { return X; }
        void set( float value ) 
            { 
                X = value; // THROWS EXCEPTION
            }
    };
    property float Y {
        float get() { return Y; }
        void set( float value ) { Y = value; }
    };
    property float Z {
        float get() { return Z; }
        void set( float value ) { Z = value; }
    };
};
```

I make a new copy of it:

```
Coord^ playerRotation = ref new Coord();
```

I try to set one of the properties' values:

```
playerRotation->X = 0.0f;
```

It runs to this part of my class code:

```
X = value; // THROWS EXCEPTION
```

and throws an exception:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00115299 in Game.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x008E2FD0).
```

What am I doing wrong with the C++/CX properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about C++/CX, but guessing from the error message

> Stack overflow

doing `X = value;` is actually calling `X::set()` which in turn does `X = value;`... you go into an infinite loop and thus causes a stack overflow.

Based on [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh755807.aspx), you need to define a backing store variable for `property X`.

```
ref class Coord
{
    float m_x;   // Backing store for property X

public:
    property float X {
        float get() { return m_x; }
        void set( float value ) 
            { 
                m_x = value;
            }
    };
...
```

You might also want to do the same for `property Y` and `property Z`.